# Solving an ODE using integrating factor

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Supposed we have the 1st order ODE:

$xy'(x)+(k-1)y(x)= (k-1)x$

with boundary conditions $y(0)=0$

Proceding to solve by integrating factor, we have:

$y(x)= \frac{(k-1)x}{k}+ \frac{C}{x^{k-1}}$

However, at the current stage, we cannot have $x=0$ to solve for C.

How would we proceed on from here?

Thanks!

Comment: Simply set $C=0$ so that you *can* have $x=0$.

Comment: If $k <1$, the ODE will be satisfied for any value of $C$. If $k\geq 1$, only $C=0$ as David H commented.